# SQL Query to match records with/without all defined many-to-many matches

Tags: mysql, sql, select, many-to-many

I have three tables, `posts`, `tags`, & `postTags`. As you can probably guess, `posts` holds information about blog posts, `tags` holds information about that tags that are in use on the system, and `postTags` holds the relationships between `posts` and `tags`.

Now, lets assume I know the `tagID`s of each tag I am looking for, as well as ones I dont, what would be a suitable, what would be a suitable query to fetch all the `posts` that match the criteria of having all the `tagID`s I specify on one list, and having none of what I specify on another?

One way I can work out is:

```
SELECT
    `posts`.*,
    CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(`postTags`.`tagID`), ',') AS `pTags`
FROM
    `posts`
INNER JOIN
    `postTags`
    ON
    `postTags`.`postID` = `posts`.`postID`
GROUP BY
    `posts`.`postID`
HAVING
    `pTags` LIKE '%,2,%'
    AND
    `pTags` LIKE '%,3,%'
    AND
    `pTags` NOT LIKE '%,5,%'
```

This query will select all the posts that have been tagged by tagID 2 & 3, and not tagged by tagID 5. But this seems potentially quite slow, especially when the data is being filtered by a large number of tags.

**EDIT**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74074)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to optimize the query with EXISTS Strategy:

```sql
SELECT
    `posts`.*
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM `postTags` 
      WHERE `postTags`.`postID` = `posts`.`postID`
        AND `postTags`.`tagID` = 2
    )
    AND
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM `postTags` 
      WHERE `postTags`.`postID` = `posts`.`postID`
        AND `postTags`.`tagID` = 3
    )    
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM `postTags` 
      WHERE `postTags`.`postID` = `posts`.`postID`
        AND `postTags`.`tagID` = 5
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do joins against a couple of sub selects, avoiding correlated sub queries.

Something like the following (not sure you need the concatenated list of tags in the SELECT, but left it there for now)

```
SELECT `posts`.*,
    CONCAT(',', Sub1.TagList, ',') AS `pTags`
FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT postID, GROUP_CONCAT(`postTags`.`tagID`) AS TagList, COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
    FROM postTags 
    WHERE tagID IN (2, 3) 
    GROUP BY postID 
    HAVING TagCount = 2
) Sub1
ON posts.postID = Sub1.postID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT postID
    FROM postTags 
    WHERE tagID IN (5) 
) Sub2
ON posts.postID = Sub2.postID
WHERE Sub2.postID IS NULL
```

Comment: Ooh, i like that, very nifty

Answer (score 1):

I believe it bring the posts you want.

```
SELECT 
    p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pt.tagID)    
FROM
    posts p
    inner join postTags pt on p.postID  = pt.postID
WHERE
not exists (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        Tags t
    WHERE
        t.tagID in (2,3)
        AND not exists
        (
           select 1 from postTags pt where pt.postID = p.postID and pt.tagID = t.tagID
        )
)
and not exists(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        Tags t
    WHERE
        t.tagID in (5)
        AND exists
        (
           select 1 from postTags pt where pt.postID = p.postID and pt.tagID = t.tagID
        )
)
GROUP BY p.postID
```